# Custom SCSS files not working on Bigcommerce Stencil

Tags: sass, bigcommerce, scss-mixins, stencil-compiler

I imported the custom SCSS files in the theme.scss but files are still not working

in theme.scss:  @import "mixins";

This should import my custom scss file named: _mixins.scss file which is is the same directory of theme.scss  but it isn't working I keep on getting an error on my _navPages.scss that mixin are not defined... even though I defined them in that _mixins.scss file

Please advise....

[file structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTrqv.png)
Example for mixin in my _navPages.scss:

```
@include for-phone-only {
 //@media (min-width: 321px) { @content; }
  grid-template-areas: "burger logo icons";
 grid-template-columns: 40px 1fr 40px;
}
```

Example for the defined mixin in my _mixins.scss:

```
 @mixin for-phone-only {
    @media (min-width: 321px) { @content; }
  }
```

Comment: Can you show your code and you styles structure as well?

Comment: Try using this...
@import "_mixins";